# Biggest opening game wins by Stanley Cup defending Champions

Tags: trivia, ice-hockey, nhl

The Washington Capitals dominantly beat the Boston Bruins 7 to 0 on their opening game of 2018 season. The Capitals won the Stanley Cup the previous season for the first time in their team history.

What are the top 5 biggest opening game wins by the defending NHL champions?

Comment: Perhaps [this tweet](https://twitter.com/PR_NHL/status/1047818671098400768) (posted [also in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/29021/2018/10/8)) might help you get an answer. Although it would be nice to find a more reliable source.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Shamelessly stealing from [NHL's Public Relations department](https://twitter.com/PR_NHL/status/1047818671098400768) (which is a plenty reliable source) plus using Pro Hockey Reference game logs for verification and goal difference, here are the top 5 biggest opening game wins by defending Stanley Cup Champions (the year being the calendar year the respective team won the Stanley Cup):

- 1976 Montreal Canadiens: [9 goals](https://www.hockey-reference.com/boxscores/197610070MTL.html) (10-1)
- 1965 Montreal Canadiens: [7 goals](https://www.hockey-reference.com/boxscores/196510230MTL.html) (8-1)
- 2018 Washington Capitals: [7 goals](https://www.hockey-reference.com/boxscores/201810030WSH.html) (7-0)
- 1942 Toronto Maple Leafs: [5 goals](https://www.hockey-reference.com/boxscores/194210310TOR.html) (7-2)
- 1938 Chicago Black Hawks: [5 goals](https://www.hockey-reference.com/boxscores/193811030CBH.html) (6-1)

Comment: Please add a link to the  NHL PR source you mentioned, also note that this does not match the tweet mentioned in the question's comments

Comment: @alamoot Link added. What doesn't match the tweet? I don't follow.

Comment: The list you provided is not the same list as the one in the tweet

Comment: @alamoot You asked for biggest opening game wins by defending Stanley Cup champions. The tweet provides most goals scored in the opening game by defending Stanley Cup champions.

Comment: perfect, that's what I want